# Reactjs authentication: does every component have to know if logged in?

Tags: reactjs, authentication

I have an existing sample application that I want to add authentication/login to. I know the frontend now has to provide a login page but will every existing page have to be changed to be aware of whether the user is logged in or not?

Comment: You can update the state value from ```isLogged = true```` and pass it to all components and containers. <br/> You can use redux to manage your state and it will be easy to pass to each n every component and container.

Comment: so u are sating every component would need to check if user was logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the component but generally yes, if the component relies on user information or the user being logged in then it should make sure the user exists.

There are a couple of things though, if you are using an auth library some of them allow integration with React-Router which means you can protect routes to only allow access to signed in users, this means if they can access your page then they must be signed in and therefore all components should be able to access the user.

Also, some will give you access to a hook useAuth() for example which allow you to get the user information and so you can fetch some information and even perform a sanity check to make sure the user is still logged in.

Another way to handle this if you are using Redux you can store your user information there and easily access it. I use this approach because it lets me update settings and information quickly and easily.